# datadog elasticsearch check failed with ReadTimeout

Tags: elasticsearch, datadog

I am trying to integrate datadog to elasticsearch but the datadog collector shows an error . i am not able to troubleshoot this. pls help

```
2017-07-14 13:49:28 UTC | ERROR | dd.collector | checks.elastic(__init__.py:812) | Check 'elastic' instance #0 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/__init__.py", line 795, in run
    self.check(copy.deepcopy(instance))
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks.d/elastic.py", line 418, in check
    pshard_stats_data = self._get_data(pshard_stats_url, config)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks.d/elastic.py", line 578, in _get_data
    cert=cert
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 499, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

My elastic.yaml

```
init_config: null
instances:
-   url: http://localhost:9200
    pshard_stats: true
    tags:
      - 'role:elasticsearch'
```

Comment: hmm, sounds like the `http://localhost:9200/_stats ` endpoint isn't available on the server you're running the dd-agent on. Maybe worth confirming that by curling it? (Maybe also curling as the `dd-agent` user?)

Or maybe you need to add some additional [configs for authentication](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/elastic/conf.yaml.example#L33-L34)?

Comment: i changed the url to the correct one and also i added cluster_stats: true but still i am getting this error.

Comment: hmm, and any luck from curling whatever is this new url with the `/_stats` endpoint? might be worth hitting up `support@datadoghq.com` at this point--they'll be quick to respond and give some help. They'll probly ask for a [flare](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204991415-Send-logs-and-configs-to-Datadog-via-flare-command)

Comment: @stephenlechner I added timeout and it fixed it. yes curling did help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool" error can be corrected by adding a timeout parameter under instances in the elasticsearch.yaml

```
 timeout: 8
```

Comment: Yes, if you look at the journalctl error it shows clearly `(read timeout=5)` which is too low a value for Elasticsearch. Increasing the timeout to 30 solved my issue.